# Azure SignalR Error: (429) Too Many Requests

Tags: c#, azure, signalr, azure-signalr

I am using Azure SignalR with Asp.Net MVC API (with .net framework not .net core) project. I can never connect to Azure's SignalR service (tried any possible configuration) while everything works fine when signalr is self-hosted.

As I enable CLR exceptions (under Exception Settings pane by checking everything under Common Language Runtime Exceptions) I keep getting the two following errors:

**1. System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (429) Too Many Requests.'**

**2. System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException: 'Unable to connect to the remote server'.
Inner Exception
WebException: The remote server returned an error: (429) Too Many Requests.**

I am using SignalR Free tier but also tried with Standard tier and ended up with the same results.

I keep checking "Connection (max)" graph under "Overview" tab on Azure portal and observing "Server 20, client 0" all the time.

The first time I got the error I assumed I really tried connecting too many times and reached maximum connection/attempt and gave up trying. After some time (approximately 24 hours) I only tried three times and still getting the same exception (429 - too many requests).

This is my configuration (in `Startup.cs`):

```
app.MapAzureSignalR(
                "/signalr",
                GetType().FullName,
                new HubConfiguration
                {
                    // tried all combinations of boolean values below.
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                    EnableJSONP = true,
                    EnableJavaScriptProxies = true
                }, options =>
                {
                    options.ConnectionCount = 5; // tried increasing and decreasing that number.
                    options.ConnectionString = "<my connection string from azure portal signalr service>";
                    options.AccessTokenLifetime = TimeSpan.FromDays(1); // tried even removing.
                }
            );
```

This code runs on my local machine, not on Azure's AppService. However, it won't run on AppService either. Because it is easier to debug on local machine, I have been trying on local machine.

I searched on the internet but have not found anything related to my issue.

How do I solve the problem?

**EDIT:**
I have the following packages installed.

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net472" />
```

Comment: Hi, will you be able to solve this issue? I have hanging Server connections, which are not closed, so 429 error appear.

Comment: No, sadly. I went with not using .net core for SignalR as I didn’t have more time spending on it.

Comment: For future users, I'm sharing link [Troubleshooting guide for Azure SignalR Service common issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-troubleshoot-guide#429-too-many-requests-returned-for-client-requests)

Answer (score 6):

**Edited**:

How many `hub`s are defined in your server-side? The **server connection count** for AspNet SignalR is `(hub count + 1) * options.ConnectionCount`

---

For **Free** instances, there are 2 dimensions of limits:

1. **Concurrent** connection count <= 20
2. **Total** message count sent per day <= 20K (refreshed every day at 12:00am UTC time).

There is no message limit for **Standard** tiers.

[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/signalr-service/) is the pricing detail for Azure SignalR Service.
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-messages-and-connections) explains in detail how messages and connections are calculated.

Comment: Don’t do this. This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @JustWork How many hubs you have? the server connection count for AspNet SignalR is `(hub count +1) * options.ConnectionCount `

Comment: I had published my code to an Azure service and had forgotten to stop it. Then when I was running it locally against a Free tier Azure SignalR Service, I encountered the `429 (Too Many Requests)` error. Then I realized I was running the free tier and each service you have connected is considered a `Unit` and the free tier only allows a single unit.